# Is there a way to track progress during parallelized Random Forest building?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, random-forest, r-caret

I'm using R's caret package to do modeling for Coursera class on machine learning.

I'm currently building Random Forest with 500 trees on a data set of 11k observations and 40 features.

It took about 3 hours for single core implementation to compute results and I'm experimenting with multi-core implementation right now (code below)

```
library(parallel)
library(caret)
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

cl <- makePSOCKcluster(4)
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(foreach))
registerDoParallel(cl)

trCtrl <- trainControl(allowParallel = TRUE)

modFit2 <- train(classe~ ., data=training, trControl = trCtrl, method="parRF", prox=TRUE, ntree = 500)
```

**Now my question is this: Is there a way to view progress on build model during run-time? Is there a package/implementation of parallelized RF that outputs for example progress on number of trees built as it run?**

Obvious question is: why do I need to know? Cant I just wait this hour or two for results? It wont be faster but might be slower that way!

I have a lot of models to build for my class and I dont want to spend few hours on each model and wonder if it is running or not. I want to confirm that it is building trees, stop execution and schedule it for the night when I will run full models. I will be running different configurations of parameters for RF and also some other time intensive models so I would rather spend my day-time on writing code while leave my computer on the mercy of running computation full speed when I'm sleeping (my browser is barely working right now :P as both my RAM and CPU are almost at 100%)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `getModelInfo` to add `cat` statements to the `fit` function. Also, there is a `verboseIter` option in `trainControl` that you are ignoring here.

Probably the problem is that you are using `trainControl(allowParallel = TRUE)`. This is going to try to fit the resampling iterations across different cores and using `method="parRF"` fits each of those in parallel.

If you specify 4 cores on your machine, you have probably spawned 16 workers. You are probably better off using `method = "rf"` and `trainControl(allowParallel = TRUE)`. That might also mean that you have 17 copies of the data in memory.

Comment: Thx fir a tip on verboseiter, seems that ineed to take a closer look at all options those package have.